# Greedy css :not() selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, theming

Is there a way to match an element that has no parent with specific selector ?

Specific use-case:

Theme is defined using 'theme' attribute.
It's required to have some part within the application with different theme.
So the DOM structure is something like:

```
<div theme="theme-A">
  // ... theme-A content
    <div theme="theme-B">
      // ... theme-B content
    </div>
  // ... theme-A content
</div>
```

Components have a css for each theme, example:

```
[theme=theme-A] .my-component{...}
[theme=theme-B] .my-component{...}
```

My attempt of solving the problem was to prevent intermediate themes like so:

```
[theme=theme-A] :not([theme]) .my-component{...}
[theme=theme-B] :not([theme]) .my-component{...}
```

But this approach doesn't work because there are other elements without 'theme' attribute in the way.

I assume I need a kind of 'greedy' :not selector, which means "no elements at all matching the condition".

Is there such a selector or trick ?
Any other suggestions / directions to try ?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no such thing. If the worry is that `.my-component` within `[theme=theme-B]` gets styles applied from `[theme=theme-A] .my-component` that you did not explicitly overwrite for theme B - then maybe you want to just reset them all first, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

Comment: Maybe direct children would help?

So `[theme=theme-B] > :not([theme]) > .my-component`. Other than that I'd agree with Cbroe that you could only reset most styles (e.g. color, bg, padding, margin) before each theme

Comment: @elveti there are arbitrary number of nested elements in between, so direct child is not an option.

Comment: @CBroe indeed thats the problem. 'all' is nice one, thanks for pointing out. But unfortunately this will reset styles of other libraries as well, so it doesn't seem to be an option. As a last resort I'll make sure that all theme overrides will cancel one another, however it'll be very cumbersome..